# How to upload an image to iNaturalist using php cURL?

Tags: php, curl

Have been working on posting observation photos to iNaturalist using iNaturalist POST/observation_photos [api](https://www.inaturalist.org/pages/api+reference) using php cURL but I am not able to do so. Did some research and found [this](https://github.com/inaturalist/inaturalist/issues/1483) on github, I tried the code but got error 'status':422.

My code:

```
<?php
require './init.php';

if ( isset($_POST['submitfile']) )
{
    // Make sure there are no upload errors
    if ($_FILES['upfile']['error'] > 0)
    {
        die("Error uploading file...");
    }
    $token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $file_path = 'c:\Users\hp\Pictures\New folder';

    $suffix = 'image/jpeg';

    $photo_name = $_FILES['upfile']['name'];

    $inat_id = 'White Magnolia';

    $boundary = rand(10,100);
    $body = '';
    $body .= '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename=' . basename($file_path) . "\"\r\n";
    $body .= 'Content-Type: ' . $suffix . "\r\n\r\n";
    $body .=file_get_contents($photo_name) . "\r\n";
    $body .= '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="observation_photo[observation_id]"' . "\r\n";
    $body .= 'Content-Type: application/json' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= json_encode(['observation_id' => $inat_id]) . "\r\n";
    $body .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . "\r\n";

    $photo_payload = array('observation_photos'=>array(
        'method'=>'POST',
        'timeout'=>'10',
        'headers'=> array(
            'Authorization'=>'Bearer'.$token,
            'Content-Type'=>'multipart/form-data;'
        ),
        'body' => $body
    ));
    $payload = json_encode($photo_payload);

    print_r($payload);

    echo "<hr><br>";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.inaturalist.org/v1/observation_photos?access_token=".$token);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.inaturalist.org/v1/observations?access_token=".$token);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Print the result?
    print_r($result);
}
?>
 <hr>
 <br>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="upfile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submitfile">
</form>
```

The error that I get while uploading image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spot 1 or 2 problems.

1. `$file_path = realpath('white magnolia.jpg');` Shouldn't this be a file path (a location) rather than an actual file name?
2. Is it possible that your `$photo_name('white magnolia.jpg')` needs an underscore instead of a space? `$photo_name('white_magnolia.jpg')`

I'm almost certain item 1 above is your main problem, but I thought I'd point out the possibility that you might need an underscore just in case.

Comment: made some changes to the code but again no change :(

Comment: I see you changed your path. But you should try to have that image somewhere within your webroot. So maybe it would look like this:
$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/'; for example